# Netflix-Xyboard error: "Sorry we could not reach the Netflix service. (1009)"

Tags: netflix, motorola-droid-xyboard

Rest of the error message: "Please try again later.  If the problems persists(sic) please visit the Netflix website."

I successfully used Netflix streaming video for over a week on my new Xyboard 8.2.  Suddenly, in the middle of a show, it started giving this error (and stopped streaming).

I tried other shows and different connections (WiFi and 3G).  I uninstalled and re-installed the updates to the factory version several times.  Rebooted several times.  Called Netflix, who said I should contact Motorola and re-install from scratch.  Rooted the Xyboard instead and installed from scratch. No change.

Netflix doesn't even think Xyboard is a supported device, although Motorola advertises it for the Xyboard.  The tech said they haven't gotten a rash of calls about this error.

All but the "1009" in the error messages seems to have occurred many a time on other devices with lots of weird resolutions that don't seem applicable and the few I've tried.

Any additional suggestions?

This was the coolest feature I found on the xyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's Motorola fault and I've found temporary workaround for me (Motorola Xoom 2 / Android Honeycomb 3.2). 
Unfortunately only device factory reset is working. Before I had tried clear cache and data, uninstall Netflix app - nothing is working. Only factory reset.

Answer (score 0):

Or you have not paid your service does not have a good internet connection. Check your account for view the payments